# SVG's Within Websites & Graceful Fallback To .png?

Tags: jquery, html, svg, png, modernizr

How do people currently code in SVG's in their pages?

I have seen this thread, from Todd a great front-end developer:

http://toddmotto.com/mastering-svg-use-for-a-retina-web-fallbacks-with-png-script/

I have also see this one, from Chris another well known developer:

http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

People have used the HTML Element "Object", however I would like to see some people that already have more experience than I. What is best practise for using SVG with png, on the pretence that you have to support only IE8 and above, the focus being on targeting newer browsers.

I have the .png's for most of my .svg's with .ai's of the most of the graphics.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Tricks link from your question gives the answer.

```
<img src="image.svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='image.png'">
```

or

```
if (!Modernizr.svg) {
  $(".logo img").attr("src", "images/logo.png");
}
```

Comment: Yeah I saw this, however I wanted to get a wider range of info on this topic. Chris has some great ideas, but the world is a big place :)

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite is the [clown car technique](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/02/clown-car-technique-solving-for-adaptive-images-in-responsive-web-design/). Essentially, you can include a png src inside of inline svg, and it will only show svg to svg browsers and png to browsers that don't

Comment: I am currently using picturefill.js on a current project page in another project. But as above, wondered if there were a better, can you imagine how many lines of HTML it would create if I had a site full of SVG's (currently @ 50+)... Thanks for the reply